# order raws based on name and number of header python

Tags: python, string, csv, sorting, numbers

I have a csv file with raws of different sizes that contain values and a header for each raw.

```
00_A1_s1
00_A1_s2
00_A1_s3
04_A1_s1
04_A1_s2
04_A1_s3
08_A1_s1
08_A1_s2
08_A1_s3
```

and I want to group the raws by the name and then order them by the number in front of the coordinates

```
00_A1_s1
04_A1_s1
08_A1_s1
00_A1_s2
04_A1_s2
08_A1_s2
00_A1_s3
04_A1_s3
08_A1_s3
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you clarify "and then order them by the number in front of the coordinates"? You want 1st to order wrt the last two characters, `sx` and then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sort` built-in function with the `key` parameter which accepts a function where you can infer the order condition on the elements. It returns a new list.

```
# file names
l = """00_A1_s1
00_A1_s2
00_A1_s3
04_A1_s1
04_A1_s2
04_A1_s3
08_A1_s1
08_A1_s2
08_A1_s3"""

l = l.split('\n') # file names as list

# sort wrt the last group of characters
print(sorted(l, key=lambda p: p.split('_')[-1]))
```

Output

```
04_A1_s1
08_A1_s1
00_A1_s2
04_A1_s2
08_A1_s2
00_A1_s3
04_A1_s3
08_A1_s3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` and use `tuple` for each item that is most important in sorting order like below:

```
txt = """00_A1_s1
00_A1_s2
00_A1_s3
04_A1_s1
04_A1_s2
04_A1_s3
08_A1_s1
08_A1_s2
08_A1_s3"""

lst = txt.split('\n') 

def orderSort(item):
    splt_itm = item.split('_')
    # first sorting on `A*` then on `s*` and at end consider number
    return (splt_itm[1] , splt_itm[2] , splt_itm[0])
    

result = sorted(lst, key=orderSort)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

Output:

```
00_A1_s1
04_A1_s1
08_A1_s1
00_A1_s2
04_A1_s2
08_A1_s2
00_A1_s3
04_A1_s3
08_A1_s3
```

Comment: ...no need for the `lambda` if you implemented such custom ordering function: `sorted(lst, key=orderSort)`